# Subset table - Matlab

Tags: matlab

In the code below I generate a table with the following results

Table:

```
ID    Age    Weight    Height     Zip      LastName  
__    ___    ______    ______    _____    ___________

1     38      176        71      11176    {'Sanchez'}
2     43      163        69      11163    {'Johnson'}
3     38      131        64      11231    {'Lee'    }
4     40      133        67      21213    {'Diaz'   }
5     49      119        64      12869    {'Brown'  }
```

code:

```
ID = [1;2;3;4;5];
LastName = {'Sanchez';'Johnson';'Lee';'Diaz';'Brown'};
Age = [38;43;38;40;49];
Height = [71;69;64;67;64];
Weight = [176;163;131;133;119];
Zip = [11176;11163;11231;21213;12869];
mltable = table(ID,Age,Weight,Height,Zip ,LastName);
```

How can I subset it and based on cloumns and by modifying the table function (`table(ID,Age,Zip ,LastName`);)

```
ID    Age     Zip      LastName  
__    ___    _____    ___________

1     38     11176    {'Sanchez'}
2     43     11163    {'Johnson'}
3     38     11231    {'Lee'    }
4     40     21213    {'Diaz'   }
5     49     12869    {'Brown'  }
```

Comment: so you just want to delete\create a new table without the weight and height columns?

Comment: Based on [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html#bt0ysyl-2), I would expect `mltable(:, {'ID', 'Age', 'Zip', 'LastName'})` to work, but I don't have MATLAB to test it.

Comment: that is correct...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
mltable(:,[1 2 5 6])
```

This uses the columns to include.

Or, using the headers

```
mltable(:,{'ID','Age','Zip' ,'LastName'})
```

Or, you can create a new table:

```
table(ID,Age,Zip ,LastName)
```